# What are all the possible abnormalities in our body that will result in ataxia?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, anatomy

So I know that ataxia is caused by loss of proprioception.I only know that dorsal column medial leminiscal pathway carries proprioceptive fibre to the cerebellum.So in theory damage to either this pathway or to the cerebellum will cause ataxia.Is there any another way that will result in ataxia?

Comment: Welcome. What makes you ask this question? Some background on the motivation of the question can help. The problem with this kind of question is that it is a very specialized topic (our community is relatively small, yet we cover a fairly big chunk of science), but the question itself is really broad (is there any one other cause of X?). I doubt you will get a satisfactory answer with the question in its current state.